# different position of items in a listview xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, listview, xamarin, listviewitem

I'm trying to use Listview. 
First i used it to have my items in a column align, it worked

Now I'm trying to search a solution to have not align my items in column.

For this I have a grid with 8 rows and 8 columns.

I want the first item in : 
`Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column ="1"`
I want the second item in : 
`Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column ="3"`
I want the third item in : 
`Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column ="3"`
I want the fourth item in : 
`Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column ="1"`

Do you think it's possible ? do you have any idea? 
I did ever read ItemView and listview documentation but i didn't find anything about grid position.

King Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need customize the Grid .

#### Grid

```
public class MyGird: Grid
{
    Label first;
    Label second;
    Label third;
    Label fourth;


    public MyGird()
    {
        this.BindingContextChanged += MyGird_BindingContextChanged;


        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        }

        first = new Label { };
        second = new Label {  };
        third = new Label { };
        fourth = new Label {  };

        Children.Add(first, 0, 0);
        Children.Add(second, 2, 2);
        Children.Add(third, 5, 2);
        Children.Add(fourth, 7, 0);
    }

    private void MyGird_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as Grid;
        var obj = grid.BindingContext as List<string>;

        first.Text = obj[0];
        second.Text = obj[1];
        third.Text = obj[2];
        fourth.Text = obj[3];
    }
}
```

#### Data

```
 public List<string> list { get; set; }
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

#### Usage

```
<local:MyGird BindingContext="{Binding list}"/>
```

Comment: You're right , thanks a lot for this exemple, and i know principe of renderer in xamarin now,  thanks a lot